# How to perform such join tables in ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need help in doing the following join using ActiveRecord relation models:

```
select "access_urls"."id", "controller_urls"."controller", "action_urls"."action" from
"access_urls"
inner join "controller_urls"
on "controller_urls"."id" = "access_urls"."controller_url_id"
inner join "action_urls"
on "action_urls"."id" = "access_urls"."action_url_id"
```

Where I have AccessUrl, ActionUrl and ControllerUrl models

```
class AccessUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :controller_url
  belongs_to :action_url
end

class ActionUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :access_urls
  validates :action, presence: true, uniqueness: { message: "já encontra-se em uso." }
end

class ControllerUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :access_urls
  validates :controller, presence: true, uniqueness: { message: "já encontra-se em uso." }
end
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables):

```
result = AccessUrl.joins(
  :controller_url, :action_url
).select(
  'access_urls.id, controller_urls.control, action_urls.action'
)
```

This will give you a relation `result` containing objects of `AccessUrl`.  You can loop through the `result` and access the selected columns as:

```
result.each do |r| 
  # r.id
  # r.control
  # r.action
end
```